# ZF2 PostgreSQL db adapter bug

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework2

Has anyone encountered a bug with table names using the PostgreSQL adapter in ZF2?

I have a column named UserId and when I try to update/delete a row based on this I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column 'userid' does not exist
```

as opposed to `UserId`.

This is my code:

```
$delete = $this->delete(
        'Users'
        , array(
             'UserId = ?' => $UserId
        )
    );
```

Might have something to do with `autoQuoteIdentifiers` but I couldn't find much online about it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940765/how-can-disable-quote-join-zend-db

Comment: I've had yes. The problem was that camel case column names need to be enclosed in double quotes so the array should have been `array('"UserId" = ?' => $UserId)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that camel cased column names need to be enclosed in double quotes so the array should be:

```
array('"UserId" = ?' => $UserId)
```